# How to evaluate double integral with sines and exponentials

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

As part of showing that $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{1+\sin x \sin y}{2 \pi} e^{-\left( \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2}\right)}$ is a probability density function, I need to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dy dx = 1$.

Normally, when I see integrals like this, I convert to polar coordinates, so I have that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dy dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1+\sin x \sin y}{2 \pi} e^{-\left( \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2}\right)} dydx \\ = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+\sin(r\cos \theta)\sin(r \sin(\theta))}{2\pi} e^{-\left( \frac{r^{2}}{2}\right)}rdr d \theta \\=  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{-\left( \frac{r^{2}}{2}\right)}rdr d \theta +  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(r\cos \theta)\sin(r \sin(\theta))}{2\pi}e^{-\left( \frac{r^{2}}{2}\right)}rdr d \theta $$

Now, after this last equals sign, the first integral is easy, but I have absolutely no idea how to do the second integral.

Is this even the correct way to show that the integral of $f(x,y) = 1$, or is there an easier way? I'm extremely stuck and need help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the integral (leaving $2\pi$ aside) as
$$
\int_{{\Bbb R}^2}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\,dxdy+\int_{{\Bbb R}^2}\sin x\, e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\cdot \sin y\,e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\,dxdy.
$$
Now the second integral reduces to iterated integration
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}\int_{\Bbb R}\sin x\, e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\cdot \sin y\,e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\,dxdy=\int_{\Bbb R}\sin y\, e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\Bigg(\underbrace{\int_{\Bbb R}\sin x\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx}_{=I}\Bigg)\,dy=I\cdot \underbrace{\int_{\Bbb R}\sin y\, e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\,dy}_{=I}=I^2.
$$
The integrand of $I$ is an odd function, so $I=0$.

Comment: I would like to be able to accept this, but I don't understand the justification behind $\sin x \sin y\, e^{-\left( - \frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2}\right)}= \sin x \,e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}} \cdot \sin y\, e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{2}}$.

Comment: Also,  do we need any conditions in order to be able to write the double integral as an iterated integral?

Comment: @DaenerysDracarys Just use $e^{a+b}=e^a\cdot e^b$ to split $$e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}}=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\cdot e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}.$$ The integral converges absolutely, it is no problem for iterated integration ([Fubini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem))

Comment: @DaenerysDracarys That's right.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the first double integral is one. Now we claim that the second double integral is zero, simply split the outer integral to $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}$ and a change of variable $\theta=\theta'-\pi$ will lead to $\displaystyle\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}=\int_{0}^{\pi}$ with the same integrand, so they double: 
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(r\cos\theta)\sin(r\sin\theta)d\theta&=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(r\cos\theta)\sin(r\sin\theta)d\theta,
\end{align*}
now split again to 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(r\cos\theta)\sin(r\sin\theta)d\theta+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\sin(r\cos\theta)\sin(r\sin\theta)d\theta
\end{align*}
for 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\sin(r\cos\theta)\sin(r\sin\theta)d\theta
\end{align*}
use $\theta'=\theta-\pi/2$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\sin(r\cos\theta)\sin(r\sin\theta)d\theta=-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(r\cos\theta)\sin(r\sin\theta)d\theta.
\end{align*}

Comment: this is incredibly clever. Thank you!

Comment: except for one thing: $\cos(\theta^{\prime} - \pi) = \cos \theta^{\prime} \cos \pi + \sin \theta^{\prime} \sin \pi = - \cos \theta^{\prime}$ and $\sin (\theta^{\prime} - \pi) = \sin \theta^{\prime} \cos \pi - \cos \theta^{\prime} \sin \pi = - \sin \theta^{\prime}$, so they don't cancel each other. Could you have meant a different change of variable, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry for the messed up, now please check, I think it works.

Comment: @DaenerysDracarys, I have checked several times that $\sin(\theta'+\pi/2)=\cos\theta'$ and $\cos(\theta'+\pi/2)=-\sin\theta'$, so now this times it should be no problem.