# How do I show that these marginal distributions do not uniquely determine the joint distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is related to a question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512979/how-to-evaluate-double-integral-with-sines-and-exponentials). In this problem, I had to check that $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{1+\sin x \sin y}{2 \pi} \exp\{-\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2} \}$ is a bivariate density, which I've done. Then, I had to derive the two marginal densities, which I've found to be $\displaystyle f_{1}(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $\displaystyle f_{2}(y) = \frac{e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $.

The remaining part of the problem is to illustrate that marginal distributions cannot uniquely determine a joint distribution; however, I am not sure how to do that. I was thinking if I could somehow come up with another distribution whose marginals were the same as these but was obviously different than what I have here, then I would have finished the problem. However, I'm not sure how to come up with one. Could somebody please help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bivariate standard normal distribution has those marginals....

Comment: ooo. Really? How nice.